# My ALT+Left Click to edge select stopped working

Tags: edges

So I'm just wondering if someone could help me figure out why my edge select doesn't work I can select edges just not an edge-loop using alt+left-click

***edit***
Emulate 3 button mouse was on

Comment: If that **edit** was the reason for the problem you should add it as an answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DERP!!p 
Emulate 3 button mouse was on..